# ColorPrimaryDark theme android doesnt display in all Activities

Tags: android, colors, themes, material-design, android-appcompat

I use a theme in my application to set `colorPrimary`, but `colorPrimaryDark` is display only on **mainActivity** I don't understand why.

Manifest :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".views.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".views.AddActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add"
        android:parentActivityName=".views.MainActivity" />
```

and theme :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

All my activities extends `AppCompatActivity`.

EDIT : Even when i use setTheme in my activity colorPirmaryDark havn't effect ...Maybe the problem is after MainActivity because i use drawer ???

layout xml MainActivity :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="@dimen/navigation_elevation"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

EDIT 2 : Rendering in Android Studio display colorPrimaryDark ...

Comment: You can explicitly call `setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)` in `onCreate()` for all activities if you want to

Comment: Yes  i can  but is  better to do this only one time  ....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `colorPrimary`, `colorPrimaryDark` and `colorAccent` can have alpha channel. Make sure you define your these colors as #RRGGBB (not #AARRGGBB). Check if it works. Also, `theme-v21` should be `theme`. What I have in my projects, if it helps you:

```
values/styles.xml

<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
</resources>


values-v21/styles.xml

<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <!-- Your style items for Lollipop -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

In Android Studio, you should see a little square with the color in the left bar. Finally, it's better to define your colors in `values/colors.xml`

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I forgot alpha channel ...; ^^ I have theme-v21 and theme to do other thing but both are the same for this part.I try it's still same problem :/. I don't understand why color is display on the mainActivity but not on other Activity .....